# How to measure ratio between lines in a photo

Tags: opencv, projection, measure

I'm working with OpenCV for a task on measuring the solar angle in a photo (without any camera parameter). In the photo there is a straight stick with the height of 3 meters standing in the middle of the field. The shadow it casts, however, lies obliquely on the ground (not in the same projection plane as the stick). I can obtain the pixel length of the stick and shadow, but I don't know if the ratio should be directly calculated with the two numbers, since only lines within the same projection plane have the same scale.

This is more like a graphic issue rather than algorithm. Can anyone shed some light on me about how to determine the height-shadow ratio?

Comment: Can you use a calibration photo?  As long as the camera and orientation remain constant, a single photo taken a known time seems like it should provide the ratio between height and shadow.  This ignores the questions of the surface upon which the shadow is being cast, as well as the angle of the sun.

Comment: I do not have the calibration photo. And I was thinking that if some part of the shadow is closer to the camera plane, it should look longer in image length while the object itself looks smaller than it actually is. Thus the ratio here is not accurate when directly measured.